# iPad application submission with iPhone SDK beta 5 rejected

Tags: ipad, app-store-connect

I try to send an specific iPad Application to iTunes connect before March 27 and as Apple says:
"Only iPad apps compiled with iPhone SDK 3.2 beta 5 will be accepted for this initial review."
So I compiled my application with iPhone SDK 3.2 beta 5 with a distribution provisioning profile.

But when I upload my application on iTunes Connect, I have the following error:
"The binary you uploaded was invalid. A pre-release beta version of the SDK was used to build the application"

For sure, it's the beta 5 !

Have you got an idea?

Thank you in advance.
Fred

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I have resolved my problem:

In xCode, choose in Project menu > Set active SDK -> iPhone Device 3.2

And now when you build your application, you obtain the logical following message:

"Error Starting Executable -  No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected".

but your .app is well build and if you look inside it, you have the file "embedded.mobileprovision".